# Kohana 3.3 - Profiler/Debug toolbar

Tags: kohana, kohana-3.3

Is there any Profiler/Debug toolbar compatible like [this](https://github.com/biakaveron/debug-toolbar) or [this](https://github.com/Alert/profilertoolbar) with Kohana 3.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kohana Debug Toolbar has a 3.3 branch:

https://github.com/biakaveron/debug-toolbar/tree/3.3